# Incorrect results/output of MATLAB vs C++ using Eigen matrices

Tags: c++, matlab, c++11, eigen, fftw

I am comparing my MATLAB code to c++ and getting incorrect output for something fairly simple.

My MATLAB code:

```
Ny = 10; 
ygl = -cos(pi*(0:Ny)/Ny)'; %Gauss-Lobatto chebyshev points 
%Chebyshev matrix: 

VGL = cos(acos(ygl(:))*(0:Ny)); 
dVGL = diag(1./sqrt(1-ygl.^2))*sin(acos(ygl)*(0:Ny))*diag(0:Ny);
```

C++ code:

```
    static const int ny = 10; 
    std::vector<double> ygl(ny+1); 

    for (int i = 0; i< ny+1; i++){
        ygl[i] = -1. * cos(((i) * EIGEN_PI )/ny); //This is correct
    
    }
    Eigen::Matrix< double, ny+1, 1> v ;
    v.setZero();

    Eigen::Matrix< double, ny+1, 1> v1 ;
    v1.setZero();

    Eigen::Matrix< double, ny+1, ny+1> m; 
    m.setZero();

    Eigen::Matrix< double, ny+1, ny+1> m1;
    m1.setZero();

    Eigen::Matrix< double, ny+1, ny+1> dv; 
    dv.setZero();
    
    for (int j = 0; j < ny+1; j++){
            v[j] = 1./(sqrt(1-pow(ygl[j],2)));
            v1[j] = 1. * (j);
        
    }
    m = v.array().sqrt().matrix().asDiagonal(); //this is correct
    m1 = v1.array().matrix().asDiagonal(); //this is correct

    for (int i = 0; i < ny+1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < ny+1; j++){
            dv(j + ny*i) = m(j) * sin(acos(ygl[j]) * (i)) * m1(j); //this is incorrect
            cout << dv(j + ny*i) << "\n";
        }
    }
```

As you can see finding the diagonal matrix of the two column vectors v and v1 are correct but then when multiplied with an additional term give completely off results. I am not sure if it's as simple as order of operation here or something else.

To give more context for this specific example, the correct output should look like:

```
 NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
         0    1.0000   -3.8042    7.8541  -12.3107   16.1803  -18.4661   18.3262  -15.2169    9.0000    0.0000
         0    1.0000   -3.2361    4.8541   -4.0000   -0.0000    6.0000  -11.3262   12.9443   -9.0000   -0.0000
         0    1.0000   -2.3511    1.1459    2.9062   -6.1803    4.3593    2.6738   -9.4046    9.0000    0.0000
         0    1.0000   -1.2361   -1.8541    4.0000    0.0000   -6.0000    4.3262    4.9443   -9.0000   -0.0000
         0    1.0000   -0.0000   -3.0000    0.0000    5.0000   -0.0000   -7.0000    0.0000    9.0000   -0.0000
         0    1.0000    1.2361   -1.8541   -4.0000   -0.0000    6.0000    4.3262   -4.9443   -9.0000   -0.0000
         0    1.0000    2.3511    1.1459   -2.9062   -6.1803   -4.3593    2.6738    9.4046    9.0000   -0.0000
         0    1.0000    3.2361    4.8541    4.0000   -0.0000   -6.0000  -11.3262  -12.9443   -9.0000    0.0000
         0    1.0000    3.8042    7.8541   12.3107   16.1803   18.4661   18.3262   15.2169    9.0000   -0.0000
       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%
After taking the suggestion of @Cris Luengo from the comments. I have the following,

```
Eigen::Matrix< double, 1, ny+1> v1;//rewrote v1[j] = 1. * (j); from for loop
v1.setZero();
std::iota(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 0);

for (int j = 0; j < ny+1; j++){
            v[j] = 1./(sqrt(1-pow(ygl[j],2)));
            //v1[j] = 1. * (j); 
    }
m = v.array().matrix().asDiagonal(); 
m1 = v1.array().matrix().asDiagonal(); 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ny+1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < ny+1; j++){
            ygl[j] = -1. * cos(((j) * EIGEN_PI )/ny);//this is correct
            dv(j + ny*i) =   sin(acos(ygl[j]) * (i));//this is correct

        }
    }
dv1 = (m) * (dv) * (m1);
std::cout << dv1 << "\n"; //this is incorrect
```

Comment: `*` is matrix multiplication in MATLAB. `acos(ygl(:)) * (0:Ny)` multiplies a column vector with a row vector, yielding a square matrix. `diag(1./sqrt(1-ygl.^2)) * sin(acos(ygl)*(0:Ny)) * diag(0:Ny);` multiplies three square matrices together. In C++ you are doing element-wise multiplications.

Comment: huh I see, is there a way to do this using Eigen in C++?

Comment: `matrix * matrix` is a matrix multiplication in Eigen also. Just don't loop over the matrix.

Comment: Well, I am not sure how to express the column and row multiplication in C++ without looping over the matrix( i.e. this expression ``sin(acos(ygl[j]) * (i))``  )

Comment: With Eigen you can express that the same way as in MATLAB. Make a column vector, make a row vector, and multiply them.

Comment: I am able to make a row vector using Eigen but, I am trying to make a column vector with  as the following: `` Eigen::Matrix< double, ny+1, 1> v2 = sin(acos(eygl) );`` but this gives the error: ``no instance of overloaded function "acos" matches the argument``

Comment: and ``eygl`` is defined as 
``for (int i = 0; i< ny+1; i++){
  ygl[i] = -1. * cos(((i) * EIGEN_PI )/ny); 
 
 }
 Eigen::VectorXd eygl = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd, Eigen::Unaligned>(ygl.data(), ygl.size());``

Comment: There might not be an acos function overloaded for matrices. Iterate over the matrix elements to apply the acos function. But the multiplications are matrix operations, not element-wise ones.

Comment: `acos` is [available as coefficient-wise operation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html#title6), compare also [this page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html).